# Django form's not valid

Tags: django

This question might be asked alot in stackoverflow but i couldn't find the answer.
Take a look at code:

```
# models.py
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    posted = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body
```

views.py:

```
class RoomInsideView(View):
    template_name = 'room/room_inside.html'
    form_class = SendMessageForm
    room = None

    def get(self, request, room_id, room_slug):
        self.room = Room.objects.get(id=room_id)
        if self.room.is_private:
            return redirect('room:private_room_auth', self.room.id)
        form = self.form_class()
        context =  {
                    'room': self.room,
                    'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, room_id, room_slug):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           new_msg = Message(body=form.cleaned_data['body'])
           new_msg.user = request.user  in
           all_messages = Message.objects.filter(room=self.room)
        messages.error(request, 'form not valid', 'warning')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'message': all_messages})
```

forms.py:

```
class SendMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ('body',)
        widgets = {
            'body': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                           'placeholder': 'Send'}),
        }
```

template:

```
    <form method="post" action="" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
        {{ form.body.errors }}
        {{ form.body }}
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
```

as I added a messages.error if form is not valid it's returning form not valid and I can't find where am I doing wrong

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: no that's not the answer . it's working properly in this case , I also try ur way but I'm getting the error.
django itself doesn't return an error . i just added a messages.error in views and it's returning a message error

Comment: @RezaJeffrey: *what* message error?

Comment: my own defined error 
messages.error(request, 'form not valid', 'warning')

form not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always add the warning, regardless whether the form is valid or not, this does not make much sense.

That being said, you are writing too much boilerplate code, you can use a [**`CreateView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) which will eliminate most of the boilerplate code:

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

```
class RoomInsideView(View):
    template_name = 'room/room_inside.html'
    form_class = SendMessageForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('name-of-some-view')

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['room'] = get_object_or_404(Room, pk=self.kwargs['room_id'], is_private=False)
        return context

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        messages.error(request, 'form not valid', 'warning')
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.room_id = self.kwargs['room_id']
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The *`name-of-some-view`* should be replaced with the name of the view where the view should redirect to in case of a successful POST request, this is done to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get architectural pattern* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).